# Sybase - Windows 7

Tags: sap-ase

Moving from XP to Windows 7 with client side.

Running into a couple issues with Sybase 15.

1) "Interactive SQL" - many widgets in ie options are defective or missing

2) When running simple query get Swing/AVT widget exception error.

Anyone ran into or worked thru any issues moving to 7?

Answer (score 1):

Other versions of the Windows app, but not 7. As you may be aware 7 is only slightly more reliable than Vista.

Those messages are classically due to (a) Sybase Client (SybaseCentral; InteractiveSQL, the GUI utilities) all using the Java VM and (b) that not being successfuly installed.

Get the Sybase Client CD, and install again. Do not Customise, use the Default installation options. Watch the progress for errors. Ensure the JVM installation succeeds.  You may have to retrieve any missing files from the Windows 7 CD.

Otherwise open a Support Case.